# How to fetch Whatsapp contact number using NotificationListenerService android?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I am trying to develop an android app which detects incoming Telephony and Whatsapp calls and fetch caller contact/phone number. I am able to detect Telephony calls using BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.w("Caller", "Called");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                String phoneNumber = extras
                        .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.w("Caller", phoneNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that I am unable to fetch Whatsapp calls using this code.
I have tried NotificationListenerService. Whenever an incoming call is made a notification is posted on Whatsapp. I can detect incoming calls but I can fetch contact details from notification which is posted.
Here is my code for NotificationListenerService

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if(sbn.getPackageName().equals("com.gbwhatsapp"))
    {
        Log.e("Called", "Sbn Key : "+ sbn.getKey());
        Bundle bundle = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        if (bundle != null) {
            for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                Log.e("Called", key + " : " + (bundle.get(key) != null ? bundle.get(key) : "NULL"));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
//"com.whatsapp"; // Personal    
//"com.whatsapp.w4b"; // Business

if (sbn.getPackageName().equals("com.whatsapp")){ 
    String title = sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
    String text = sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT).toString();    
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it only gives the Contact Name. I had to run a ContentResolver Query to search a conract manually